# "Motait" : French? Creole? Root?

Tags: traduction, créole

*Quand Motait Piti*
Song by Brian Carrick and his Heritage Hall Stompers

Can't translate "motait".

It is said to mean "When I was a kid".

Answer (score 3):

The sentence means ***Quand j'étais petit*** in [Louisiana Creole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louisiana_Creole) (not to be confused with Louisiana French).

It looks and sounds like *Quand moi était petit* (when me was little) and literally translates to "**When I was little**", i.e. "**When I was a kid**".

Like all other French based creoles, Louisiana Creole uses a first person personal pronoun derived from the disjunctive pronoun ***moi*** (me) instead of the standard one ***je*** (I).

| Louisiane | Guyane | Grenade | Seychelles | Maurice | Réunion | Guadeloupe | Haïti | Martinique | Sainte-Lucie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mo | mo | mo | mo/mon | mwen | mwen/mi | mwen/an | mwen | mwen/man | mwen |

Comment: Thanks so much! Brilliant answer. Fits with Cajun English and everything I already experienced. You are appreciated.